# Union of two Arrays without default functions in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I've preparing for my Interviews and I've completed the Union of two Arrays in Java. I searched the Internet and it has lot of examples but everything utilises a default function available in Java like Set, etc.. I dont want to use default function whichever may give advantage to my program. Because that is the way companies are going to give me problems like "AuB without using any default functions". So I spend 30 min and atlast I found a solution. I'm not asking any questions, I just need people to give suggestions on my logic whether it's good or it's the dumpest logic which you've seen till now and It'll also be helpfull if anyone looking for solutions without utilising default functions.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Union {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Size of A array: ");
        int asize = input.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[asize];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print("a["+i+"]: ");
            a[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter size of B array: ");
        int bsize = input.nextInt();
        int[] b = new int[bsize];
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            System.out.print("b["+i+"]: ");
            b[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        int count;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            count = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                if(a[i]!=a[j]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count==i){
                list.add(a[i]);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            count = 0;
            for(Integer e:list){
                if(b[i]!=e){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count==list.size()){
                list.add(b[i]);
            }
        }
        for(Integer e:list){
            System.out.print(e+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `list.sort(null)` is correct/not a built in function.

Comment: It's just an extra step, I dont want to sort it. For clearence I'll remove it now. Thanks.

Comment: "I'm not asking any questions..." Remember that Stack Overflow is a Question & Answer site. If you are not asking a question, then we cannot give an answer.

Comment: If you can sort the arrays, you can do a merge sort which would be simpler/more efficient. Or you can sort the combined arrays and de-duplicate.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  Yeah, I know. I've also posted some foolish posts which wasted some time to me and also to the members. I'm not worried about my downvotes, I thought suggestions may fall into category of Answers even without asking questions. Kindly delete my thread if it's not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears Fine.

A simple logic modification that you can do is instead of using count++ for every repeated values,just
put the integers from Array A to your ArrayList<> and when putting the next integer from Array A just parse through the ArrayList<> to check whether we have the number already present. Then same can be done for Array B.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably avoid using java.util.List completely since this problem is supposed to be purely about arrays.  You know the size of both arrays and could store the data in an array of size a.length + b.length, since you know that the length of the union will never exceed that.

Comment: Yeah, the third array will not exceed both a+b size, but the remaining elements in third array will be having 0 and it'll also print the 0(s) at the end.